# Node.js memory leak causes system to lose available memory, even after node restart?

Tags: node.js

According to nodetime, my memory leak is persisting even through node application restarts. Check out the following "OS - Free Memory" graph; notice how the memory decreases steadily (despite the node app restarting dozens and dozens of times) until I restart the whole server:

[image]

How is this possible? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something? I don't understand how a memory leak in one process could survive and continue to affect the OS...

Machine Info:
Amazon EC2 (m1.large) running CentOS

Comment: You have not provided information about the OS, but no you are not wrong in assuming that memory leaks cannot survive a process death/restart. Also, it is not clear what you mean by "restart the whole server" (vs application restart).

Comment: Restarting the server means... restarting the server. Turn it off. Turn it back on (or, rather, re-lease a new machine from the cloud). I've also edited the post to include machine info.

Answer (score 0):

A memory leak in one process (that is actually killed) can't do this.

Are you using 3rd party systems to provided shared state? For example, a database, or something like redis for sessions? In that case, restarting your node process will just lead to reconnecting to the same shared state and continuing whatever leak was started initially.